# How can I delete part of a ring in photoshop cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I want to delete parts of a ring but I want to do it precisely (with photoshop CS6),  example in pictures: (How can I do this easily?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried coping and pasting another ring and deleting sections of it where I want to delete the ring, but I want to have more flexibility in terms of the length and everything on the parts I want to delete and this way is a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the pen tool to achieve your outcome picture

first id set up some guides to make sure your alignments are correct and then id use the pen tool to pull a shape i desired now in your outcome i'm not sure if its meant to be a straight line or have sharp corners at the end.

[image]

then id create a masking layer on top of the logo layer

then id go back to my pen tool right click and fill my pen tool shape in with Black onto the masked layer. This allows you to go in and make changes to the logo in a none destructive manner

[image]

Hope thats what you was looking for.

Comment: Setting up multiple guides (horizontal and vertical) can help to accurately get the desired shape with this method.

Answer (score -1):

**It probably because you are working with a low-resolution file.**

Photoshop is a raster graphics editor.So it will pixelate.In order to override the issue please work with a high-resolution file like the below image.But when you are zooming more than 100% it will look like pixelated.

[image]

> Use illustrator or any other vector graphics editor to overcome the issue 100%